# React-router-dom v6 showing blank pages except default URL

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router-dom

For some reason when I try to go from *localhost* to *localhost/Products* or anywhere other than *localhost*, a blank page is shown. I cannot figure out why yet. On *localhost* the correct components are shown: App.js which has Navbar, Home and Footer.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import DashboardApp from './DashboardApp';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min";
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter,Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Account from './pages/Account';



render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<App />} />
    {/* <Route path='/Login' element={<Login />}></Route> */}
    <Route path='/Account' element={<Account />}/>
    <Route path='/Dashboard' element={<DashboardApp />}/>
    </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Besides that I have more Routes inside the DashboardApp component which are not working properly, when I try to enter one of the URLs it always redirects me to App.js except for the *localhost/Dashboard* URL which loads the correct page. Though this might be an unrelated issue.

```
import Products from "./pages/Products";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import AboutUs from "./pages/AboutUs"
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Footer from "./components/sections/Footer";
import {NavBar} from "./components/sections/NavBar";
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'mdb-react-ui-kit/dist/css/mdb.min.css';
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";


export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar/>
      <Routes>      
          <Route path="" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/Products' element={<Products/>}/>
          <Route path='/Contact' element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path='/AboutUs' element={<AboutUs />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer/>
    </>
    
  );
}
```

Comment: A blank page is usually accompanied by error messages in your dev-tools _Console_. Take a look

Comment: Had completely overlooked that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `App` and `Dashboard` components are rendering ***descendent*** routes, so the parent route must append a wildcard `"*"`, also known as ["splats"](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats), matcher which indicates a route can match all its sub-routes.

Example:

```
<StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/*' element={<App />} />
      {/* <Route path='/Login' element={<Login />}></Route> */}
      <Route path='/Account' element={<Account />}/>
      <Route path='/Dashboard/*' element={<DashboardApp />}/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
</StrictMode>
```

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Routes>      
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/Products" element={<Products />} />
          <Route path="/Contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/AboutUs" element={<AboutUs />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  );
}
```